# Delay on Marker Title in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, markers, title

I am trying to put title on leaflet markers. [This](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/7678758) explains the way to give title to marker which would appear on hover. Is there any way we can set time on that i.e. make the title appear after 50ms of the mouse hover?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to alter the speed of the native title tag. It's implemented by the browser.

You would have to look at a custom title implementation using a plugin or similar, something like [qTip](http://qtip2.com/) perhaps.